# Dropdownlist not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

Why is the property `DEPARTMENTID` not inserting into the database on create, I am using `Dropdownlist`
see the code below, this all my code i need your idea to correct my code.

**Controller**

```html
// GET: /Budget/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
var name = User.Identity.GetUserName();

var userroles = _roleDataContext.USERROLEs.Where(u => u.USERNAME.ToLower().Trim() == name.ToLower().Trim() && u.ROLE.Trim() == "6");

var rolegroup = from u in userroles.ToList()
join rg in _roleDataContext.ROLEGROUPs.ToList()
on u.ROLEID equals rg.ROLEID
select rg;

var usergroup = (from rg in rolegroup.ToList()
join ug in _roleDataContext.USERGROUPs.ToList()
on rg.GROUPID equals ug.GROUPID
select ug).OrderBy(i => i.DEPTCODE);

var listSelectitem = usergroup.Select(@group => new SelectListItem
{
Selected = true,
Text = @group.DEPTCODE.Length > 20 ? @group.DEPTCODE.Substring(0, 20) : @group.DEPTCODE,
Value = @group.DEPTCODE
}).ToList();

var firstOrDefault = usergroup.FirstOrDefault();
if (firstOrDefault != null)
{
ViewBag.DeptList = new SelectList(listSelectitem, "Value", "Text", firstOrDefault.DEPTCODE);
}
return View();
}

// POST: /Budget/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(BudgetViewModel model , int month = 1, int year = 2017)
{
// TODO: Add insert logic here
model.DATETIME = DateTime.Now;
BudgetDb.insert(model);
return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**View**

```html
@model WarehouseRtoRSystem.Models.BudgetViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<style>
    .col-md-10 {
        clear: both;
        padding-left: 0px !important;
    }
    .col-md-2 {
        text-align: left !important;
    }
</style>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal">
<h2>Budget</h2>
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<label>Month </label>
<select id="month" name="month">
@{ string[] Months = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" }; }
@for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
var m = i + 1;
if (Convert.ToInt32(ViewBag.month) == m)
{
<option value=@m selected>@Months[i]</option>
}
else
{
<option value=@m>@Months[i]</option>
}
}
</select>
<label>YEAR</label>
<select id="year" name="year">
@for (var c = 0; c < 1000; c++)
{
var yr = c + 2017;
if (Convert.ToInt32(ViewBag.year) == yr)
{
<option value=@yr selected>
@yr
</option>
}
else
{
<option value=@yr> @yr</option>
}
}
</select>
<br />
<br />
<div class="form-group">
<label>&nbsp; &nbsp;LIST OF YOUR DEPARTMENT</label>
<span class="">@Html.DropDownList("DEPARTMENTID", (SelectList)ViewBag.DeptList, new { @class = "form-control" })</span>
</div>

 

<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.BUDGET, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
@Html.TextBox("ShowBudget", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BUDGET, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BUDGET)
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { @class ="btn btn-primary"})
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#ShowBudget").change(function () {
            var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
            $("#BUDGET").val(value); //assign the current value to BUDGET field

            if (!isNaN(value)) {
                var result = value.toLocaleString(
                    "en-US", // use a string like 'en-US' to override browser locale
                    { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }
                );
                $(this).val(result);
            }
        })
    })
</script>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Model**

```
namespace WarehouseRtoRSystem.Models

{
public class BudgetModel
{
public int MONTH { get; set; }

public int YEAR { get; set; }  

public string DEPARTMENTID { get; set; }

public DateTime DATETIME { get; set; }

//[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

public double BUDGET { get; set; }

public string GROUPID { get; set; }

}

public class BudgetViewModel : BudgetModel

{

public string DEPARTMENTNAME { get; set; }

public double EXPENCES { get; set; }

public double BALANCE { get; set; }

}

public class BudgetContext

{

private readonly OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

private OracleConnection Conn = new OracleConnection();

private readonly OracleConnModel ORCONN = new OracleConnModel();

public List<BudgetViewModel> List()

{

var Departments = new List<BudgetViewModel>();


///SQL QUERY

Conn = ORCONN.con;

if (Conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)

{

Conn.Open();

}

try

{

cmd.Connection = Conn;

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From PH.SYSTEMBUDGET";

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())

{

var Dept = new BudgetViewModel();

Dept.MONTH = dr.GetInt32(0);

Dept.YEAR = dr.GetInt32(1);

Dept.DEPARTMENTID = dr.GetString(2);

Dept.DATETIME = dr.GetDateTime(3);

Dept.BUDGET = dr.GetDouble(4);

Dept.GROUPID = dr.IsDBNull(5) ? "" : dr.GetString(5);

Departments.Add(Dept);

}

}

finally

{

Conn.Close();

}

return Departments;

}


public string insert(BudgetModel model)

{

Conn = ORCONN.con;

if (Conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)

{

Conn.Open();

}

try

{

cmd.Connection = Conn;

//var date = new DateTime();

// date = DateTime.Now;

var query = "INSERT into PH.SYSTEMBUDGET(";

query += "MONTH,";

query += "YEAR,";

query += "DEPARTMENTID,";

query += "DATETIME,";

query += "BUDGET,";

query += "GROUPID";

query += ")";

query += "VALUES(";

query += "'" + model.MONTH + "',";

query += "'" + model.YEAR + "',";

query += "'" + model.DEPARTMENTID + "',";

query += "TO_DATE('" + DateTime.Now + "','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),";

query +=  "'"+ model.BUDGET + "'," ;

query += "'" + model.GROUPID + "'";

query += ")";

cmd.CommandText = query;

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}

catch(Exception e)

{

Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);

}

finally

{

Conn.Close();

}

return "Seccessfully inserted";

}

}

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Does it goes all the way through on your httppost create?

Comment: no error sir will show

Comment: Can you post the code on your view model as well? Also the html/razor code of your whole form, not just the drop down list.

Comment: the departmentID field in your view isn't a dropdown list, just a textbox. You seem have got the department list added to a field called "groupID" instead. Is that the intention?

Comment: does the model contain DepartmentID when it's posted back to the server? Does the code throw any exceptions during execution? If so what errors are there? And also why are you building your queries using strings like that? Please learn to use SQL parameters otherwise your code is a) easily prone to difficult-to-spot syntax errors, and worse, SQL Injection attacks where a malicious user could easily steal, corrupt or delete your data.

Answer (score 0):

The error resides in the following code in your controller, whereby you are setting the `Value` of the `SelectListItem` to be the DEPTCODE description instead of the ID of the DEPTCODE record

Here is your code:

```
var listSelectitem = usergroup.Select(@group => new SelectListItem
{
Selected = true,
Text = @group.DEPTCODE.Length > 20 ? @group.DEPTCODE.Substring(0, 20) : @group.DEPTCODE,
Value = @group.DEPTCODE
}).ToList();
```

The issue is here:

```
Value = @group.DEPTCODE
```

Now apologies for not re-creating the code exactly in the controller but the DEPTCODE models were not available, so I improvised slightly.

Here is my Create Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    List<DeptCode> _depts = new List<DeptCode>();
    _depts.Add(new DeptCode { Id = 0, Description = "IT"});
    _depts.Add(new DeptCode { Id = 1, Description = "Customer Services" });
    _depts.Add(new DeptCode { Id = 2, Description = "Warehouse" });


    var _listSelectItem = _depts.Select(@group => new SelectListItem
    {
        Selected = true,
        Text = @group.Description,
        Value = @group.Id.ToString()

    }).ToList();

    var firstOrDefault = _listSelectItem.FirstOrDefault();
    if(firstOrDefault != null)
    {
        ViewBag.DeptList = new SelectList(_listSelectItem, "Value", "Text", firstOrDefault.Text);
    }

    return View();
}
```

I have created my `SelectListItem` with the `Value` of the `Id` of the record, because in your code, you were binding `ViewBag.DeptList` with a `SelectList` whereby the `dataValueField` ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.)) property was **"Value".**:

```
ViewBag.DeptList = new SelectList(_listSelectItem, "Value", "Text", firstOrDefault.Text);
```

So in my example I have selected a **Warehouse** department (again I made this value up for the sake of my model), and pressed **Create.**:

[image: My View]

As you can see, this is now bound to `model.DEPARTMENTI`D:

[image]

I have added my code here if you want to see how it works:

https://github.com/garfbradaz/StackOverFlowAnswers/tree/master/ASP.NET%20MVC/DropDownListNotWorking/SOAnswer-44879268